# Any way to set Min,Max Limits for Slider in Google Maps ( Flex )?

Tags: google-maps, flex4

I wan to set minimum ans maximum zoom limit for slider in Google Maps , but in Flex Implementation.

Same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706865/google-maps-setting-minimum-and-maximum-slider-controls) before . But the question as well as answers are for Javascript implementation .

I interpreted in Flex , but got error :

> Cannot assign to a method getMinimumResolution on com.google.maps.wrappers.IMapTypeWrapper.

what i did:

```
var mt:Array = gmap.getMapTypes();

                for (var i:int=0; i<mt.length; i++) {
                    mt[i].getMinimumResolution = function() {return 6;}
                }
```

how to set it in Flex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tweaked it a liitle bit and here's the soln:

```
gmap.addEventListener(MapZoomEvent.ZOOM_CHANGED, onZoomChanged);
```

And the Eventlistener :

```
public function onZoomChanged(e:MapZoomEvent):void 
            {
                var inProcess:Boolean = false;
                if (inProcess) return;

                if (e.zoomLevel > 16) 
                {                   
                    inProcess = true;
                    gmap.setZoom(16);
                    inProcess = false;
                    return
                }
                else if (e.zoomLevel < 13) 
                {                   
                    inProcess = true;
                    gmap.setZoom(13);
                    inProcess = false;
                    return;
                }   }
```